How to cut a complex shape out of a mesh and retain mesh
What is the easiest way to cut a sphere like shape out of another sphere like shape with all mesh topology rejoining?
I resorted to doing this manually, cutting vertices and rejoining them in the past but that took forever, surely there is an easier way?


You could create these edge loops with the knife (K to activate, A to cut orthogonally, C to cut through), then remove the oblique edges:

Or you could shear the sphere (AltCtrlShiftSX):

Then Face > Intersect (Boolean) and choose Union in the Operator Box:

Correct the topology:


This looks like a simple Boolean operation. Select one of the spheres entirely (the other one not at all), and run Face -> Intersect (Boolean) on it . After that, you can choose in the operator properties panel between Difference, Union, and Intersect for the type of Boolean operation that you want. See the Intersect (Boolean) operator page in the Blender Manual for more information.

Sorry, none of these work for me...
When I do face - Intersect Boolean - Union, it does not merge the topologies

@Fred_was_here would you show a screenshot of what it does do? AFAIK, this is what Boolean is meant for.
